# Файл настроек websphere

Tags: java, websphere

Ну удается запустить websphere application server после изменения настроек памяти, начальный размер кучи и максимальный я оставил поля пустыми, не запускается сервер, думается это из за того что не хватает памяти для уже установленных приложений, где хранятся настройки, или где добавить команды xms и xmx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Настройки java heapsize хранятся в server.xml 
Путь к файлу: /путь установки websphere/profiles/имя профайла/config/cells/имя ячейки/nodes/имя ноды/servers/имя сервера/server.xml

В файле server.xml есть блоки "processDefinitions" и "jvmEntries"
Заменить значения в  initialHeapSize="" maximumHeapSize=""

Пример блока

```
<jvmEntries xmi:id="JavaVirtualMachine_11831234130079" 
verboseModeClass="false" verboseModeGarbageCollection="true" 
verboseModeJNI="false" **initialHeapSize="256" maximumHeapSize="1024"** 
runHProf="false" hprofArguments="" debugMode="true" debugArgs="-
agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=7777" 
genericJvmArguments="-Xdisableexplicitgc -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xjit:
{com/ibm/db2/jcc/*}(disableIdiomRecognition)">
</jvmEntries>
```

После сохранить и запустить websphere

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere не запускается при наличии Pid файла. Обычно, этот файл расположен в директории логов. Если PID файл существует то websphere думает, что она запущена. Удалите pid файл ( pid файл просто содержит строку с указанием процесса родителя, если такого процесса в системе нет, то можно удалять файл) webspere будет стартовать со значениями по  умолчанию(25%  от доступного RAM или с ограничениями по процессу jvm). И не пытайтесь редактировать server.xml  в  word'е :-)